# Impossible to find how to add app-ads.txt on WIX site?

Tags: velo, app-ads.txt

Hello I use WIX for my site, but I only can add ads.txt and no app-ads.txt

I can't enable admob for my app without this.

Their is a solution ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  This venue is for questions about programming and software development.

Answer (score 0):

Add ads.txt and set up a redirect for it from app-ads.txt (SEO->URL Redirect Manager). I'm not completely sure, but it helped with Unity.